# Get exchange calendar events in javascript webapp?

Tags: javascript, calendar, outlook, exchange-server

I find the documentation provided by microsoft confusing([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations)).

How can I for example get an authentication token and where can I download the javascript libraries? I couldn't find any information on this.

Basically I want to know how to get the calendar of an user in my javascript webapp.

I did try sending an request to

```
"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime="+begin+"&endDateTime="+end"
```

This shows me an authentication popup but after submitting the correct username/mail and password, it doesn't do anything. There is no response back.

Comment: you have to register your app/url with MS to get a token.

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token, you need to use the OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant flow. https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted walks through the process. Basically you need to register your app to get a client ID and secret, then use those to go through the process.